# entire page scrolls when I only want one section to scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this...I'm tearing my hair out. I want to create a few sections that scroll horizontally. I looked at Netflix's code to model this, and I finally got the overflow to bleed all the way to the edges of the browser window, and the beginning and end of the row both line up with the margins on the page. But now when I scroll, the entire page scrolls.

How do I get this section to scroll independently while still letting the overflow reach the edges of the page? Is this possible with just css?

```css
body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.landing-banner {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 80vh;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* position: sticky;
    left: 0; */
}

.content-block {
    margin: 0 4%;
}

.hero {
    font-family: "Apercu-Regular";
    line-height: 40px; 
}

.lolomoRow {
    margin: 3vw 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.rowContainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.rowContainer .rowContent {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4%;
    touch-action: pan-y;
}

.slider .sliderMask .showPeek {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.slider .sliderMask {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.sliderContent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider .sliderMask .sliderContent .slider-item:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.slider .sliderMask .sliderContent .slider-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.bd::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.project-card {
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(112, 144, 176, 0.12);
    margin-right: 16px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="landing-banner">
        <wrapper>
            <div class="row content-block">
                <h1 class="hero">
                    If you scroll anywhere, the entire page scrolls horizontally. I only want the section below to scroll while still remaining full bleed.
                </h1>
            </div>
        </wrapper>
    </div>
    <wrapper style="width: fit-content; display: inline-block; padding: 0 4%; position: sticky; left: 0;">
        <h2>case studies</h2>
    </wrapper>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="sliderMask showPeek">
            <div class="sliderContent row-with-x-columns">

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add overflow-Y: scroll; to the slider class as can be seen below. This tells it that it is what needs the scroll bar not the entire document.

Here is the MDN documentation for overflow
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```css
body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.landing-banner {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 80vh;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* position: sticky;
    left: 0; */
}

.content-block {
    margin: 0 4%;
}

.hero {
    font-family: "Apercu-Regular";
    line-height: 40px; 
}

.lolomoRow {
    margin: 3vw 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.rowContainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.rowContainer .rowContent {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  overflow-Y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4%;
    touch-action: pan-y;
}

.slider .sliderMask .showPeek {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.slider .sliderMask {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.sliderContent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider .sliderMask .sliderContent .slider-item:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.slider .sliderMask .sliderContent .slider-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.bd::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.project-card {
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(112, 144, 176, 0.12);
    margin-right: 16px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="landing-banner">
        <wrapper>
            <div class="row content-block">
                <h1 class="hero">
                    If you scroll anywhere, the entire page scrolls horizontally. I only want the section below to scroll while still remaining full bleed.
                </h1>
            </div>
        </wrapper>
    </div>
    <wrapper style="width: fit-content; display: inline-block; padding: 0 4%; position: sticky; left: 0;">
        <h2>case studies</h2>
    </wrapper>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="sliderMask showPeek">
            <div class="sliderContent row-with-x-columns">

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-item">
                    <div class="title-card">
                        <div class="project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="images/project previews/Circa.png" style="max-width: 100%">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;">
                                <h3 class="project-title">Circa Resident App</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;">
                                <p class="caption">Led end-to-end product design on Circa's customer facing app.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you want to model it after Netflix (as mentioned in the question), I don't believe they have a scroll bar usually, so that would be targeting the scrollbar for the slider and you would probably want to add something like:

```
 /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.slider {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

However for accessibility reasons it is generally frowned upon hiding scroll bars unless **blatantly** obvious that it is a scroll-able element;